# Separating compound nouns from basic nouns

Tags: python

I have a list that goes like this:

```
name = ['road', 'roadwork', 'roadblock', 'ball', 'football', 'basketball', 'volleyball']
```

Is there a code that separate the compound nouns from the basic nouns? So that I can get:

```
name = ['road', 'ball']
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can we assume that you will have at least one of the base words in the list?  For example, if the list has 'roadwork', can we assume it has either 'road' or 'work' in the same list?

Comment: Well, basic nouns are nouns are not compounded. Yes, we can assume that there will be one of the base words in the list. And since the base words "road" and "ball" exists in the list, is it possible to remove other words that contain the base words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All words that do not include any other words as a substring:

```
>>> [x for x in name if not any(word in x for word in name if word != x)]
    ['road', 'ball']
```

One way to print names using loops:

```
for candidate in name:
    for word in name:
        # candidate is a compound if it contains any other word (not equal to it)
        if word != candidate and word in candidate:
            break      # a compound. break inner loop, continue outer
    else:              # no breaks occured, must be a basic noun
        print candidate
```

Comment: Congrats, you were faster... Same idea!

Comment: Thanks! However how do we express the same line in looping? Like for x in name: if not....: print name?

Comment: Added one way to print names with loops. A rare occasion — a valid reason to use `for..else` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['road', 'roadwork', 'roadblock', 'ball', 'football', 'basketball', 'volleyball']

basic_names = [name for name in names if not any([part for part in names if part in name and part != name])]
```