# Separating compound nouns from basic nouns part 2

Tags: python

Well I previously asked a question and I got the answer what I wanted. However I have more questions now.

I have a list that goes like this:

```
name = ['road', 'roadwork', 'pill', 'pillbox', 'pillow', 'ball',
'football', 'basketball', 'work', 'box', 'foot', 'basket']
```

The code below separates the words with compound nouns from the base words:

```
for candidate in name:
    for word in name:
        if word != candidate and word in candidate:
            break      
        else:              
            print candidate
```

However I realise that the code is too restrictive because it also removes "pillow" from the list.

Is there a code that can generate the below outcome:

```
name = ['road', 'pill', 'pillow', 'ball', 'work', 'box', 'foot', 'basket']
```

Comment: The desire output is: name = ['road', 'pill', 'pillow', 'ball']. The question that I asked previously is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616565/separating-compound-nouns-from-basic-nouns

Comment: Why is "basketball" a compound word, and "pillow" isn't? And don't say, "because 'basketball' is composed of nouns 'basket' and 'ball'". There's no `basket` entry in your `name` list, so it's not a word as far as your program is concerned

Comment: Okay to better illustrate my point, I have a database of English words that consist of base words (words like "foot" and "ball") and compound words (words which are made up of two base words like "football". I would like to filter out the compound words from my database. Is there a code that searches for words that are made up of two base words and remove them from my list?

Comment: Does your database have the words "pill" and "ow"? Then your program would classify "pillow" as a compound word, even though its meaning has nothing to do with the words that make it up. Is that OK?

Comment: My database does not have the word "ow" because it is not a valid English word. I guess it is okay if the code does not eliminate "pillow" because the word "ow" does not exist in my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your average word, the simplest way to determine if it is a compound word is to chop it in half and see if both halves are words. You have to test repeatedly with different chopping points, so the run time is proportional to the length of the word. It should be reasonably fast for any English word, other than [189,000 character long chemical names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titin#Linguistic_significance).

```
words = ['road', 'roadwork', 'pill', 'pillbox', 'pillow', 'ball', 'football', 'basketball', 'work', 'box', 'foot', 'basket']

wordSet = set(words)

def isWord(w):
    return w in wordSet

def isCompoundWord(word):
    for idx in range(1, len(word)):
        left = word[:idx]
        right = word[idx:]
        if isWord(left) and isWord(right):
            return True
    return False

nonCompoundWords = [word for word in words if not isCompoundWord(word)]
print nonCompoundWords
```

output:

```
['road', 'pill', 'pillow', 'ball', 'work', 'box', 'foot', 'basket']
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find if what remains of the word after subtracting the match is another word. There will be situations, I imagine where the etymology won't match up. I'm thinking words that include another word plus 'is' where 'is' is not used as it's meaning, for example.

Edit: for example:

```
words = ['book','store','bookstore','booking']
li = []
for word in words:
    for test in words:
        if test in word:
            temp = word[len(test):]
            if temp in words and word not in li:
                li.append(word) 

for x in li:
    words.remove(x)
print words
```

Comment: Okay to better illustrate my point, I have a database of English words that consist of base words (words like "foot" and "ball") and compound words (words which are made up of two base words like "football". I would like to filter out the compound words from my database. Is there a code that searches for words that are made up of two base words and remove them from my list?